# How to use of Aws IoT certificate, access key and secret key in Swift?

Tags: aws-iot, certifications

I am new to Swift as well as to AWS-IoT.

After reading a tons of doc, I finally decide to post a question for a simple answer.

I am working on a project where I have to interact with "Things". 
I created an account on AWS and registered "My Thing," create policy and attaching that policy with certificate.

Now I have a private key, a public key certificate and an endpoint url but do not know how to use it in Swift. I checked out [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/IoT-Sample/Swift) demo, but there is no clear explanation on using private and public keys with certificates; instead of that it contains a constant file as below. What am I supposed to do with the certificate?

```
let CertificateSigningRequestCommonName = "IoTSampleSwift Application"
let CertificateSigningRequestCountryName = "Your Country"
let CertificateSigningRequestOrganizationName = "Your Organization"
let CertificateSigningRequestOrganizationalUnitName = "Your Organizational Unit"
let PolicyName = "YourPolicyName"

// This is the endpoint in your AWS IoT console. eg: https://xxxxxxxxxx.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com
let AWSRegion = AWSRegionType.Unknown // e.g. AWSRegionType.USEast1
let IOT_ENDPOINT = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com"
let ASWIoTDataManager = "MyIotDataManager
```

Please help me to understand this.